Number of students who own cats

In a classroom of 100 students, each student owns at least one pet: a dog, a cat, and/or a bird. If 41 students have a dog, 13 students have only a bird, 22 students have a cat and a bird, and 8 students have a dog and a cat, how many students have a cat?

Fo this question I drew the following Venn diagram:

where $C$ is the number of students who own only a cat, and $D$ is the number of students who own only a dog.
I found the number of students who own only a cat as follows:
$ D = 33-x-y$
$ C+D+22+8+13+x+y = 100$
$ C+33-x-y+22+8+13+x+y = 100$
$$C=24$$
Hence, 24 students own only a cat. How do I progress from here. How can I find $x$, the number of students who own all three pets, and then find the total number of students who own cats?

22 students have a cat and a bird does this include those that have all three? Same with 8 students have a dog and a cat.

Thinking of it now, the 22 students could include the ones having all three pets. I am not too sure. I posted the question exactly how it was framed.

I'm not sure there is enough information to solve this question. I can see 7 unknowns but only 5 equations, so the system can't be solved uniquely...

The Venn diagram as illustrated uses inconsistent interpretations of the question wording. It treats "41 students have a dog" as meaning "at least a dog", but "how many students have a cat"  as meaning "only a cat". I don't think this diagram represents an internally self-consistent interpretation of the question. The fact that some of the wording explicitly mentions "only" suggest to me that cases where it's missing are not meant to be exclusive - I'd think we need to solve for the number of students with at least a cat, not only a cat.

How do you suggest we can solve this?

I'm going to redefine some of the variables: $A$ is how many have all pets, $B=$ only a bird, $C=$ only a cat, $D=$ only a dog, $E=$ cat and dog not bird, $F=$ bird and dog not cat, $G=$ bird and cat not dog. We have five equations given by the following matrix (note we can't simply invert this matrix to solve the system as there aren't enough equations to solve for all the variables)
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\1&0&0&1&1&1&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\\C\\D\\E\\F\\G\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}100\\41\\13\\22\\8\end{pmatrix}$$
The answer to the question is given by $A+C+E+G$. To find this, we don't actually have to solve for every unknown...
The third equation gives $\fbox{B = 13}$.
The fourth and fifth equations give expressions for $G$ and $E$ in terms of $A$: $A+G = 22 \rightarrow \fbox{G = 22 - A}$ and $A+E = 8 \rightarrow \fbox{E = 8 - A}$.
Using this expression for $E$, the second equation gives a value for $D+F$: $41 = A+D+E+F = A+D+(8-A)+F \rightarrow \fbox{D + F = 33}$
Using all of these expressions, the first equation gives $100 = A+B+C+D+E+F+G = A+13+C+33+(8-A)+(22-A) \rightarrow \fbox{C - A = 24}$
Recall what we are looking for:
$A+C+E+G = A+C+(8-A)+(22-A) = C-A+8+22 = 24+8+22 = \fbox{54}$
So the answr is $$54$$

Can you tell me how you got this matrix? I'm quite new to this approach.

Do you know about matrix multiplication? Each row of the matrix corresponds to an equation while the column is the vector of unknowns and each row of the RHS corresponds to the RHS of each equation. When multiplying, you travel along the row of the matrix and down the column of the vector. For row $i$, the number in column $j$ is the coefficient of the variable in row $j$ of the vector in that equation

I am aware of matrix multiplication. But, I don't understand how to insert those $0$s and $1$s like you did in the first matrix.

These are the coefficients of the variables $A,\dots,G$ for each of the equations. https://youtu.be/V8lIpRHjthk?si=YM7IENZ-vcSg-xIE

Hey, following up on this. I found an easier way:
Total no. of students with a cat = no. of students with only a cat + no. students with a cat and a bird + no. students with a cat and a dog. Number of students with a cat and a dog and number of students with a bird and a cat is given. I found out the number of students with only a cat to be $24$. Therefore, total no. of students with a cat $= 24 + 22 + 8 = 54$.
